# how can I edit grids on a battleship board to represent ships in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am using subplot() and pcolor(zeros(7,7)); to produce the following figure for a battleship game (please see link below). Im trying to change the color of specific grids to represent ships, but I can't figure it out, so can I please get help with this, I need to for example change grids 22 and 23 in "your board" to red and have the existing figure updated, not get a new figure.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easiest if you set up a function to create/colour a specific square, then this is trivial, and can be recycled throughout your game. Below I've made the local function `drawSquare(bs,N,player,color)` which accepts a board size (`bs`), square number (`N`), a player (`'top'` or `'bottom'`), and a colour, which can be any valid MATLAB [`colorspec`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/specify-plot-colors.html).

Then I've made another function `setup(bs)` which calls this a bunch of times to create the "board" for each player.

Then you can see it's as simple as calling `drawSquare( bs, 3, 'top', 'r' );`  to turn the top player's square number 3 red.

Equally it's easy to call `drawSquare( bs, 4, 'top', [0.6,0.5,0.5] );` to colour square 4 for that player a grey-ish tone to show something like a "hit" square in the battleships game.

[image: board]

```
figure(100);
bs = 6; % board size
% Initialise the board
setup( bs );
% Example usage colouring in specific squares
drawSquare( bs, 3, 'top', 'r' )
drawSquare( bs, 4, 'top', [0.6,0.5,0.5] );

function setup( bs )
    clf; % clear the board
    for ii = 1:(bs^2)
        % Loop over all squares, make the base boards
        drawSquare( bs, ii, 'top', 'w' );
        drawSquare( bs, ii, 'bottom', 'w' );
    end
    % Format the plots without ticks and with titles
    subplot( 2, 1, 1 );
    set( gca, 'XTickLabel', '', 'YTickLabel', '', 'BoxStyle', 'full' );
    title( 'Computer Board' );
    subplot( 2, 1, 2 );
    set( gca, 'XTickLabel', '', 'YTickLabel', '', 'BoxStyle', 'full' );
    title( 'Your Board' );
end

function drawSquare( bs, N, player, color )
    % sq = square size, N = square number, player = 'top' or 'bottom'
    % color = valid plot colour for different square types
    x = mod(N-1,bs);        % x axis in grid
    y = floor( (N-1)/bs );  % y axis in grid
    if strcmpi( player, 'top' )
        subplot( 2, 1, 1 ); % top player is subplot 1
        x = bs - x;         % top player square 1 is bottom-right
    else
        subplot( 2, 1, 2 ); % bottom player is subplot 2
        y = bs - y;         % bottom player square 1 is top-left
    end
    xp = [x, x+1, x+1, x];  % x coordinates of grid square
    yp = [y, y, y+1, y+1];  % y coordinates of grid square
    patch( xp, yp, color ); % use patch to make coloured square
    text( x+(1/2), y+(1/2), num2str(N), 'HorizontalAlignment', 'center' );
end
```

Comment: Just put `setup` in its own function and call that function whenever you want after the play option is used. I'm afraid if you need more help you'll have to ask another _specific_ question, otherwise this one is going to creep. Please remember to include a [mcve] of the issue you're having coding it yourself. Please consider marking this answer as "accepted" if it answered this original question.

Comment: Have a read of the [mcve] page, the hope is that you can present some minimal example which demonstrates the specific issue you're having. Try and break the problem down really small to highlight the bit you're stuck on (button callbacks, calling a function, whatever), then you might even find that question has already been answered

Comment: Im sorry please ignore my last comments I realised that I did something wrong. But I do have a problem with this code itself, so ill ask here, then if im told to ask a different question ill do that. So whenever I use drawSqaure, it works fine and updates the figure but then it also gives me a different figure (figure(100);), but I do not need this new figure to show, so I tried removing figure(100); but then nothing works, so help with how to fix it will be highly appreciated.